# How to find and replace dates from one format to another in plaintext file?

Tags: text, replace

How can I most easily change dates within files from a format like this "July 13, 1958" to, "1958-07-13" or at least "1958 July 13."

Answer (score 0):

The solution here depends on if you want to do this programmatically or not.

Date reformatting from text is [easy to achieve in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-dates-stored-as-text-to-dates-8df7663e-98e6-4295-96e4-32a67ec0a680#ID0EBBH=Windows) without the need for any programming.

On the other hand if you would like to do this using JavaScript I would recommend using [Luxon Ad-Hoc Parsing Methods](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing?id=ad-hoc-parsing)

Some JS pseudo code based on your question:

```
import { DateTime } from "luxon"
import text-file from 'file with dates as plaintext'

for (let date of text-file) {
  const cleanDate = DateTime.fromFormat("July 13 1958", "LLLL dd yyyy");
  console.log(cleanDate)
}
```

UPDATE (from community):

The above works if your file has ONLY dates, one per line. If your file has mixed text with dates scattered throughout, then you will need to parse the text file and locate the date strings. Get your clean date, then replace the found dates with the clean dates throughout your text file.

Comment: Yeah. finding dates in text is a lot more difficult. I was surprised there was no available solution, to such a common problem.

"Date reformatting from text is easy to achieve in Excel without the need for any programming."
I didn't have excel available on Libreoffice Calc. I managed to get a list of dates. And it proved ridiculously horrible. It broke that dates by adding an apostrophe when I changed the column to date format, and because of this failed to recognize it when I tried changing to a different date format. A joke...